# Is the Godel universe Wick rotatable?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, wick-rotation, algebraic-geometry

Take Wick Rotatability being as the way defined in the article by Helleland:

[Wick rotations and real GIT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04576)

Is the [Gödel universe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric) Wick rotatable according to this definition?

Comment: I am not sure if it is Wick rotatable in the sense of Helleland, but the curved 2+1 part of Gödel universe can be seen as a Lorentzian version of a sphere $S^3$ stretched along the fibers of Hopf fibration. So, if $AdS_3$ is a Wick rotation of sphere according to this definition, then the answer will be yes.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1206 According to this article by Gibbons, the Wick rotation of $AdS_3$
should be rather $H^3$. 
The hyperbolic space and not the sphere. @A.V.S. Is there any reason for it to be $S^3$
 in your reasoning?

Comment: Moreover as can be checked here: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric the metric becomes complex, by the naive $t→iτ$
prescribtion. Meaning it is rather a hermitian metric. Also the 2+1 dimensional part of the Gödel metric does not seem to be $AdS_3$( at least at first sight to me) @A.V.S.

Comment: The curved part of Gödel metric is not $AdS_3$ but *stretched* $AdS$. As in we take the metric of $AdS$ and stretch it along certain timelike direction, obtaining the new metric on the same manifold. So informally, there is more time in Gödel universe than in $AdS$ and some trajectories that were superluminal/spacelike in $AdS$ are timelike in Gödel (and that is how CTC appear). The direction for stretching is given by left-invariant vector field on the manifold. For sphere this is most naturally given as Hopf vibration but analogues exist for hyperbolic and Lorentzian versions too.

Comment: Closely related crosspost: https://mathoverflow.net/q/462704/ (it is considered good practice to mention this in your question to avoid duplicate work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be Wick-rotated to a negative-definite Riemannian metric on the (Berger sphere)xR. See the my more detailed answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462704/is-the-g%c3%b6del-universe-wick-rotatable/463620#463620